# Create c# classes in specific files from json file with using NJsonSchema

Tags: c#, json, njsonschema

I have a JSON file where I've defined my models. My objective is to create individual class files for each model. I'm currently using NJsonSchema to accomplish this task. However, when I generate the classes for each root object, the final class file includes all of the classes. I'm unsure how to resolve this issue. Here's a snippet of my code:

**Generate method :**

```
        public void generateClass()
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText("json.json");
            var schemaFromFile = NJsonSchema.JsonSchema.FromSampleJson(json);
            var classGenerator = new CSharpGenerator(schemaFromFile, new CSharpGeneratorSettings
            {
                ClassStyle = CSharpClassStyle.Poco
            });
            foreach (var entity in schemaFromFile.Definitions)
            {
                var rootName = entity.Key;
                var code = classGenerator.GenerateFile(rootName);
                File.WriteAllText($"{entity.Key}.cs", code);
            }
        }
```

**JSON file :**

```
{
  "User": {
    "Username": "string",
    "Password": "string"
  },
  "LoginResponse": {
    "UserId": "int",
    "AuthenticationToken": "string"
  }
}
```

** Generated Classes : **

```
//----------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Generated using the NJsonSchema v11.0.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0) (http://NJsonSchema.org)
// </auto-generated>
//----------------------


namespace MyNamespace
{
    #pragma warning disable // Disable all warnings

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "11.0.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class User
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Username", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Password", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Password { get; set; }



        private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties;

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
        {
            get { return _additionalProperties ?? (_additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>()); }
            set { _additionalProperties = value; }
        }

    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "11.0.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class LoginResponse
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("UserId", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("AuthenticationToken", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }



        private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties;

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
        {
            get { return _additionalProperties ?? (_additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>()); }
            set { _additionalProperties = value; }
        }

    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "11.0.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class User2
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("User", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public User User { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("LoginResponse", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public LoginResponse LoginResponse { get; set; }



        private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties;

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
        {
            get { return _additionalProperties ?? (_additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>()); }
            set { _additionalProperties = value; }
        }

    }
}
```